# Why does python descriptor's __get__ run twice from IPython?

Tags: python, descriptor

I have a basic descriptor that prints it's value when set or accessed:

```
class ObservableValue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.instances = {} #instance -> value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print('setting to %d'%(value,))
        self.instances[obj] = value

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        v = self.instances[obj]
        print("getting %d"%v)
        return v


class MyObject(object):

    value = ObservableValue()

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

If I open a vanilla Python interactive session I can do this

```
>>> import MyFile
>>> mo = MyFile.MyObject(42)
setting to 42
>>> mo.value
getting 42
42
```

But if I do it in IPython I get this

```
>>> import MyFile
>>> mo = MyFile.MyObject(42)
setting to 42
>>> mo.value
getting 42
getting 42
42
```

Why does it print twice?

ADDED: If I put the object instantiation and the `mo.value` line in the imported file, it only prints once.

Comment: actually, I can't reproduce your results... only runs once and prints "getting value 42".

Comment: Definitely twice for me. I just copy-pasted code from question into file, imported, and ran. Prints twice. Python 2.6 on Win7.

Comment: Neither my Win7 Python 3.3 nor [codepad's Python 2.5](http://codepad.org/0dMBLHIw) show that behavior. Such a severe bug is unlikely to begin with, and doubly so when it's apparently both OS- and version-dependent. Coupled with the fact that your code disagrees with your example output ("setting value to 42" vs. "setting to 42" and "getting value" vs. "getting 42"), I strongly suggest you triple-check *everything* and then create a complete 1:1 runnable program + output that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Good suggestion. I now see that this only happens only when I run from IPython o_O

Comment: restart ipython (your environment must be messed up). It works as expected from a clean ipython environment as well.

Comment: I tried that and it still prints twice.

Comment: Try printing the callstack.